# AngularJS testing error on adding name parameter to scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner, angularjs-controller

Error received when running `karma start configs/karma.conf.js`:

```
INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.2 (Linux)]: Connected on socket PK-IbFeI1qpFq0fix6WI
PhantomJS 1.9.2 (Linux) IndexController should add name parameter to scope FAILED
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.6/$injector/modulerr?p0=myapp.controllers&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.6%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3Dmyapp.controllers%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9877%2Fbase%2Fpublic%2Fapp%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3F1387689655000%3A20%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9877%2Fbase%2Fpublic%2Fapp%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3F1387689655000%3A21%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9877%2Fbase%2Fpublic%2Fapp%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3F1387689655000%3A29
    at /home/Projects/abbrevi8-karma-tests/public/app/lib/angular/angular.min.js:29
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'scope.name')
    at /home/Projects/abbrevi8-karma-tests/test/unit/controllerSpec.js:19
PhantomJS 1.9.2 (Linux): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.178 secs / 0.006 secs)
```

#### public/app/controllers.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('IndexController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.name = 'bob';
});
```

#### test/unit/controllerSpec.js

```
'use strict';

describe('IndexController', function() {
    //initialise module
    beforeEach(module('myapp.controllers'));

    //params initialised in scope for tests
    var ctrl, scope;

    beforeEach(inject(function($controller) {
        //get controller from $controller provider
        scope = {}; 
        ctrl = $controller('IndexController', {
            $scope: scope
        }); 
    }));

    it ('should add name parameter to scope', function() {
        expect(scope.name).toBeDefined(); 
    }); 
});
```

Full project (same as above, only with my `karma.conf.js` and `setup.sh`): https://gist.github.com/AlecTaylor/8078807

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

`beforeEach(module('myApp'));`

instead of:

```
beforeEach(module('myapp.controllers'));
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Annoyed with the blog post that told me to write the other >.<

Comment: Ha! I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing here, as I don't have Phantom to run on Linux... but `$scope` is expected to be a Scope object.

Try injecting `$rootScope`, and either use that, or create a `$new()` child scope from it:

```
beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
    //get controller from $controller provider
    scope = $rootScope.$new(); 
    ctrl = $controller('IndexController', {
        $scope: scope
    }); 
}));
```

Comment: Thanks, but that still hasn't fixed the problem. `scope` and `ctrl` are still resolved as `undefined` :\